# How to make a table from two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting

I have two lists.

```
list1 = {115.366, 103.583, 115.24, 91.4648, 93.1291, 485.744, 427.888,489.401, 403.942}

list2 = {114.062, 105.17, 114.857, 91.6497, 93.2112, 398.588, 458.713,410.015, 380.659}
```

I want these lists to form a table that looks like this.

```
115.366    114.062
103.583    105.17
115.24     114.857
and so on
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Transpose[{list1, list2}] // TableForm
```

$\begin{array}{cc}
 115.366 & 114.062 \\
 103.583 & 105.17 \\
 115.24 & 114.857 \\
 91.4648 & 91.6497 \\
 93.1291 & 93.2112 \\
 485.744 & 398.588 \\
 427.888 & 458.713 \\
 489.401 & 410.015 \\
 403.942 & 380.659 \\
\end{array}$

Answer (score 8):

And then there is [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html):

```
transposedData = Transpose @ { list1, list2 }; (* make a list of tuples *)

Grid[
  transposedData,
  (* options for further formatting go here *)
]
```

[image: Table]

Just to give an idea of what is possible using options for `Grid`:

```
Grid[
  transposedData,
  Frame -> {All, None, {{3, 2} -> Directive[Red, Thick]}},
  Alignment -> {Decimal, Decimal}
]
```

[image: nicer table]

Answer (score 7):

Although solution has been already accepted, here is another way it could be done

### Example

**Code**

```
Row[(Column[#, Frame -> True] & /@ {list1, list2})]
```

**Note:** `list1` and `list2` as in OP

**Output**

[image: output example]

**Reference**

[Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html?q=Map)
[Row](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html)
[Column](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html?q=Column)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the [@cvgmt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/72111/cvgmt)'s feedback, alternatives to `Transpose`:

### Code 1

```
Thread[{list1, list2}]

% == Transpose[{list1, list2}]
(* Out: True *)
```

### Code 2

Can only be used on two lists, each of them should be 1-dimensional:

```
Inner[List, list1, list2, List]

% == Transpose[{list1, list2}]
(* Out: True *)
```

### Speed Comparison

```
lg[n_] := ConstantArray[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^n], 2]

thread[{l1_, l2_}] := Thread[{l1, l2}];
inner[{l1_, l2_}] := Inner[List, l1, l2, List];
transpose[{l1_, l2_}] := Transpose[{l1, l2}];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
BenchmarkPlot[{thread, inner, transpose}, lg, TimeConstrained -> 20]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `Transpose` is faster then others. `list1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^6];
list2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^6];
Thread[List[list1, list2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
Inner[List, list1, list2, List]; // AbsoluteTiming
Transpose[List[list1, list2]]; // AbsoluteTiming`

Answer (score 3):

A new approach is based on the command [**`ArrayReduce`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReduce.html) and it works in the following manner:

```
TableForm@ArrayReduce[Dot, {list1, list2}, 1]
```

Another alternative is based on the use of [**`Multicolumn`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multicolumn.html?v=13.2). It works like this:

```
Multicolumn[Flatten@ArrayReshape[{list1, list2}, {2, Length@list1}], 
   2]
```

In the above command, we can add at the end `[[1]] // TableForm` optionally. This will create a `List` and bring it into `TableForm`.

The output of the two commands above is

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: @user1066 very good points. Thanks for pointing those out. Indeed, `ArrayReduce` seems a very nice and useful gadget to have and I definitely need more practice with it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make your own function:

```
In[1]= myThread[l1__, l2__] := If[Length[l1] != Length[l2],"Error in length", {l1[[#]], l2[[#]]} & /@ Range[1, Length[l1]]]

list1 = Reverse[Range[1, 9]]
Out[1]= {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

list1 = Range[1, 9]
Out[2]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

In[2]= myThread[list1__, list2__]
Out[3]= {{9, 1}, {8, 2}, {7, 3}, {6, 4}, {5, 5}, {4, 6}, {3, 7}, {2, 8}, {1,9}}
```

You can expand the logic to any dimension. Also, applying //Tableform function at the end will format the output in the form you seek, viz.:

```
In[262]= list//TableForm
Out[263]//TableForm=
1    9
2    8
etc...
```