# Joining two lists element by element

Tags: list-manipulation, table

If I have two sets of data say, `x={1,2,3}` and `y=(4,5,6}`, and I wanted to make a table `T = {{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}`, how would I do so by using `x` and `y` and not just typing out the whole table? Is there any way that I can make a table by doing something like `Table[x,y]` after specifying the vectors `x` and `y`?

I'm asking because I want to reference the `x` values when I plot a fitted line.

Comment: `x = {1, 2, 3}; y = {4, 5, 6};
m2 = Transpose[{x, y}]`

Comment: `Thread[{x, y}]`    `Inner[List, x, y, List]`

Comment: Almost *certainly*, this is a duplicate.  Where is it?

Comment: Ah here it is: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101769/how-to-make-a-table-from-two-lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a table from two lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101769/how-to-make-a-table-from-two-lists)

Answer (score 8):

Some ways of doing it:

With

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {4, 5, 6};
```

all of the following

```
Thread[{x, y}] // MatrixForm
Transpose[{x, y}] // MatrixForm
Inner[List, x, y, List] // MatrixForm
MapThread[List, {x, y}] // MatrixForm
Table[{x[[i]], y[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[x]}] // MatrixForm
Partition[Riffle[x, y], 2] // MatrixForm
Transpose[ArrayFlatten[{x, y}], {2, 1}] // MatrixForm
Function[, {##}, Listable][x, y] // MatrixForm
Quiet@Factor[x, y] /. Factor -> List // MatrixForm
```

a variant of the last is:

```
foo[x, y] /. foo -> List // MatrixForm
```

**Edit 1:** there'a a new command called [**`ArrayReduce`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReduce.html)

```
ArrayReduce[Dot, {x, y}, 1] // MatrixForm
```

**Edit 2:** and another way

```
Multicolumn[Flatten@ArrayReshape[{x, y}, {2, 3}], 
   2][[1]] // MatrixForm
```

**Edit 3:** special thanks to @user1066 for the valuable comment. One can observe how the following behaves

```
ArrayReduce[f, {x, y}, 1] // MatrixForm
```

and from the above we can deduce that the following two commands give the desired output

```
ArrayReduce[Join, {x, y}, 1] // MatrixForm
ArrayReduce[Union, {x, y}, 1] // MatrixForm
```

All of the above give:

> [image: mat]

Comment: @user1066 many thanks for the feedback. the comment is implemented in the answer

Answer (score 7):

This is what you have

```
(mat = {{1, 2, 3},{4, 5, 6}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is what you want

```
(matWanted = {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now if you have the first form, how to obtain the second form from it? What is the name of the operation to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
Diagonal@Outer[List, x, y] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Number 10!!! Wonderful

Comment: The job is done, mate!

Answer (score 3):

No one seems to have mentioned `Flatten`

```
Flatten[{x,y},{{2}}]

(* {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}} *)
```

When dealing with 'ragged' arrays, this method may be advantageous:

Compare:

```
Flatten[{x, Append[y, 100]},{{2}}]

Transpose[{x, Append[y, 100]}]

(* 
  {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {100}} 

  Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 100}} cannot be transposed.

*)
```

The  [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html#614537583) for `Flatten` also gives an example of how to 'Do a "transpose" on a ragged array', and this usage of `Flatten` is very well explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106) by [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin)

Comment: Very nice! I knew I missed something elementary. Thanks :-)