# Elementary operations on list of points

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of points
$$L = \{\{x_1,y_1\}, \{x_2,y_2\}, \{x_3,y_3\},\cdots\{x_n,y_n\}\}$$
and I want to create a list
$$L1 = \{f(x_1,y_1), f(x_2,y_2), \cdots, f(x_n,y_n)\},$$
where $f$ is some function. Let us take the example $f(x,y) = x^i y^j.$

Is there a simple direct method? In my example, would it be possible to get the list $\{x_1^iy_1^j, x_2^iy_2^j,\cdots x_n^iy_n^j\}$ directly without defining $f(x,y) = x^i y^j$?

This might be a trivial question, but not for people who used to use Python.

Comment: If `alist = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};`, then `f @@@ alist` will do this. Or the more verbose way is to do:  `Map[Apply@f, alist, {1}]`.

Comment: `f /@ points` if f takes a list e.g `f[{x,y}]`, otherwise just `f@@@points`. This is all covered in the documentation so I'm voting to close. If you want to also pass an index, then use `MapIndexed`.

Comment: `#1^i #2^j & @@@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to spend time learning the tool and show minimal knowledge of Mathematica before posting questions. I also wish the OP good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) indexed variables as subscripts

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {x, y};

pts = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, 5]
```

[image]

[`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
f /@ pts
```

[image]

```
ex1 = #[[1]]^i*#[[2]]^j & /@ pts
```

[image]

[`MapApply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html)

```
f @@@ pts
```

[image]

```
ex2 = #1^i*#2^j & @@@ pts
```

[image]

```
ex1 === ex2

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is informative.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach (which I learned from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/279280/106) by [bmf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/85558/bmf)) is to use [`ArrayReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReduce.html)

```
m = Array[{Subscript[x, #],Subscript[y,#]} &, 5]
```

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4 }, {x5, y5}}
```

```
ArrayReduce[f, m, 2]
```

```
{f[{x1, y1}], f[{x2, y2}], f[{x3, y3}], f[{x4, y4}], f[{x5, y6}]}
```

```
ArrayReduce[Times@@{#[[1]]^i,#[[2]]^j}&, m,2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I liked this approach too.

Comment: (+1) I am very glad to see that `ArrayReduce` is gaining popularity!